# Weird issue in TinyMCE - WIRIS

Tags: jquery, tinymce, wiris

I am using **Tinymce wiris editor** to add equation. But the click button is not working. I checked the console and it show this *error*

> plugin.min.js

```
plugin.min.js:3353 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index.
at e.value (http://localhost:8080/equation/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.min.js:3353:117)
at e.value (http://localhost:8080/equation/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.min.js:3316:81)
at t.value (http://localhost:8080/equation/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.min.js:3564:22)
at t.value (http://localhost:8080/equation/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.min.js:3559:27)
at t.value (http://localhost:8080/equation/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.min.js:3760:51)
at e.value (http://localhost:8080/equation/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.min.js:2517:28)
at e.value (http://localhost:8080/equation/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.min.js:2812:72)
```

I checked the `plugin.min.js` file. but unable to find any issues there. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I faced the same issue a while ago. Try clicking anywhere inside the TinyMCE editor section before clicking the okay button in WIRIS popup. it solved my issue.

Comment: @sarathsrajendran thanks for the comment. It worked. But its not a permanent solution though. Also, its hard to explain this to clients :-)

Comment: I know. If you could validate the get range before calling it may solve the issue.